Onesignal SDK v4 to v5 migration, inapp message tag feature not found
My project includes a survey created with OneSignal (v4). When a user submits the survey, I listen for the submission through setInAppMessageClickHandler. The result sdk response contains tags, which include the user-submitted answers.
V4 code.
    OneSignal.setInAppMessageClickHandler { result ->
    result.tags?.tagsToAdd?.let { tagJson -

In version 5, the equivalent of setInAppMessageClickHandler is InAppMessages.addClickListener. but, the response does not include tags
V5 Code:
    OneSignal.InAppMessages.addClickListener(object : IInAppMessageClickListener {
        override fun onClick(event: IInAppMessageClickEvent) {

How to get tags in v5?
